# Converter for Text_Wiki to Markdown?

Tags: markdown, document-converter, wiki

I have some old texts written in [Wikidot syntax](http://www.wikidot.com/doc-wiki-syntax:start). According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikidot this markup language is based on the PHP package [Text_Wiki](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki/).

Is there any converter or code out there that can convert Text_Wiki format to Markdown? [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options) doesn't seem to support this format.

Comment: Same question here!

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote some kind of convertor:
https://github.com/IlyaOvodov/wikidot2markdown